# Как сделать чтобы при вводе команды не проверялся регистр? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пользователь пишет команду /TEAM, но в коде у меня должна быть команда /team и как сделать чтобы при любом регистре команда выполнялась?

Answer (score 0):

Преобразуйте выражение к верхнему ( .upper() ) или нижнему регистру ( .lower() )

Comment: `@client.command()
async def team(ctx, team):
    await ctx.send('team')`

Можете указать куда именно?

Answer (score 0):

туда, где получаешь сообщение от пользователя `'\TEAM'.lower()` или  же `ctx.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - через `aliases`:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['team', 'TEAM'])
async def __team(ctx):
    await ctx.send('team')
```

Если у команды множество вариаций названий, можно проверять команду в `on_message()` и приводить ее название к нижнему регистру, а затем уже передавать в обработчик команды:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(bot.command_prefix):
        splitted_content = message.content.split()
        splitted_content[0] = splitted_content[0].lower()
        message.content = ' '.join(splitted_content)
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Ваш префикс', case_insensitive=True)

                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]